# Starting the animation when the activity starts

Tags: android, eclipse

My animation is running on the button press, now i want the animation to start when the activity starts. Following is my code.

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        animationStart();

        Button onButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        onButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                animationStart();
            }
        });

    }


    private void animationStart() {
        ImageView imageanimate = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageanimate.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ball_animation);
        animation = (AnimationDrawable) imageanimate
                .getDrawable();

        if (animation.isRunning()) {
            animation.stop();
        }
        animation.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        animationStart();
        super.onStart();
    }

}
```

I have also tried to initialize the animation in onstart method but it is now working.

I want that when the acitivity starts the animation should play. Anybody could please guide me the right way to do it as it is not working. The animation ONLY works with the button press.

Comment: Is it now working or not?

Comment: what type of animation u want ?

Comment: On start of the activity it is not working. I want to have frame animation working the code for which is as mentioned above which ONLY works with the button press.

Comment: Initially you are not getting drawable for your `ImageView`. You should get `drawable` in `onWindowFocusChanged()` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start animation in onCreate or onStart, you should start animation in handler with 1000-2000 ms postdelay which will give enough time to initialize imageview.

```
 Handler handler = new Handler();
  handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
       //Start your animation here
         }
     },1000);
  }
```

Comment: I always used this but forgot it and your answer reminded me this thing again. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

I do not test it, I hope it will help you.

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      //....
      final Handler handler = new Handler();
      handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             animationStart();
         }
      },0);
      //...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean mDoStartingAnim;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
    mDoStartingAnim= true;
    // ...
}

public void onResume() {
    if (mDoStartingAnim) {
        animationStart();
        mDoStartingAnim = false;
    }
}
```

I hope it will help you..